# ASP.NET MVC routing URLs starting with numbers

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

Obviously in C# classes are not allowed to start with a number so how do I create controllers for URLs that start with a number in ASP.NET 4.6?

Example URL:

```
www.domain.com/40apples/
```

---

EDIT: Routing each URL individually will quickly become a pain to manage. Ideally, I'm looking for a solution that handles all number URLs. So that the above URL example routes to _40apples controller, 300cherries to _300cherries and 1orange to _1orange

Comment: You can't have `public class 40ApplesController` but you *can* have a `route` that will match `/40apples`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will have to use custom routing, in your RegisterRoutes method you could add another route that looks something like this:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            "ApplesRoute",                                           // Route name
            "40apples/{action}",                            // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Apples", action = "Index" }  // Parameter defaults
        );

        routes.MapRoute(
            "Default",                                              // Route name
            "{controller}/{action}/{id}",                           // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = "" }  // Parameter defaults
        );
    }
```

If you would want your route to catch anything starting with a number + apples you could use a regex-constraint. Something like this:

```
routes.MapRoute(
        "ApplesRoute",                                           // Route name
        "{number}apples/{action}",                            // URL with parameters
        new { controller = "Apples", action = "Index" }  // Parameter defaults
       ,new {number = @"\d+" } //constraint
    );
```

An even more generic approach would be to catch all routes that starts with a number + a word. Then you could build your route and constraints something like this:

```
routes.MapRoute(
        "NumbersRoute",                                           // Route name
        "{numberfruit}/{action}",                            // URL with parameters
        new { controller = "Numbers", action = "Index" }  // Parameter defaults
       ,new { numberfruit = @"\d+[A-Za-z]" } //constraint
    );
```

EDIT after discussion with Organic:

The approach that solved the problem in this case was using attribute routing. Which works well if you're using mvc 5 or greater.

Then you would add an attribute route similar to this to your controller:

```
[RoutePrefix("40apples")]
```

And then another route to every specific action:

```
[Route("{Buy}")]
```

Do not forget to add `routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();` to your route config.

Comment: Ah! What if I have dozens or hundreds of pages starting with numbers? Is it possible to create a generic rule that will handle all URLs starting with numbers?

Comment: Yes, you could do that with a regex route I believe, I'll add an example.

Comment: Updated my answer with a more generic example. If you would need to expand it to handle more routes you could probably just build on that example with more route constraints etc.

Comment: Thanks for that. Looks promising but I don't think the regex rule will handle number URLs with any text after the number. URLs to consider: *40apples, 1orange, 300cherries*

Comment: Updated with another answer that will handle your cases

Comment: You could also change [A-Za-z] to a group of names that you would want to match, like \d+(apples|oranges|cherries) That would make it possible to exclude paths like /123bread for example, but would force you to specify all fruits in the constraint.

Comment: I really like the look of it, I don;t understand it but I like it : ) So in your last example how do I need to name my controllers? I really need to get my head around regex.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114749/discussion-between-robban-and-organic).